# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' in '/codebuild/output/src489574561/src/user-management-frontend/src'

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm trying to deploy a React App in AWS Amplify but during the `Build` process, `AWS Amplify` throws below error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' in '/codebuild/output/src489574561/src/user-management-frontend/src'
```

I'm wondering how to solve this error by changing something in code or need to configure AWS Amplify.

Full log trace is here:

```
                                 # Starting phase: preBuild
                                 # Executing command: npm ci
2022-09-07T06:11:29.303Z [INFO]: > core-js@3.25.0 postinstall /codebuild/output/src489574561/src/user-management-frontend/node_modules/core-js
                                 > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
2022-09-07T06:11:29.350Z [INFO]: [96mThank you for using core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock/core-js [96m) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library![0m
                                 [96mThe project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js:[0m
                                 [96m>[94m https://opencollective.com/core-js [0m
                                 [96m>[94m https://patreon.com/zloirock [0m
                                 [96m>[94m bitcoin: bc1qlea7544qtsmj2rayg0lthvza9fau63ux0fstcz [0m
                                 [96mAlso, the author of core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock [96m) is looking for a good job -)[0m
2022-09-07T06:11:29.558Z [INFO]: > core-js-pure@3.25.0 postinstall /codebuild/output/src489574561/src/user-management-frontend/node_modules/core-js-pure
                                 > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
2022-09-07T06:11:29.895Z [INFO]: added 1501 packages in 21.092s
2022-09-07T06:11:29.908Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
                                 # Starting phase: build
2022-09-07T06:11:29.908Z [INFO]: # Executing command: npm run build
2022-09-07T06:11:30.074Z [INFO]: > user-management-frontend@0.1.0 build /codebuild/output/src489574561/src/user-management-frontend
                                 > react-scripts build
2022-09-07T06:11:31.296Z [INFO]: Creating an optimized production build...
2022-09-07T06:11:31.983Z [INFO]: Failed to compile.
2022-09-07T06:11:31.983Z [INFO]: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' in '/codebuild/output/src489574561/src/user-management-frontend/src'
2022-09-07T06:11:31.994Z [WARNING]: npm
2022-09-07T06:11:31.994Z [WARNING]: ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
                                    npm ERR! errno 1
2022-09-07T06:11:31.996Z [WARNING]: npm
2022-09-07T06:11:31.996Z [WARNING]: ERR! user-management-frontend@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
                                    npm ERR! Exit status 1
                                    npm ERR!
                                    npm ERR! Failed at the user-management-frontend@0.1.0 build script.
                                    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2022-09-07T06:11:32.000Z [WARNING]: 
2022-09-07T06:11:32.000Z [WARNING]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
                                    npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-09-07T06_11_31_997Z-debug.log
2022-09-07T06:11:32.000Z [HELP]: Outputting the npm debug log
                                 [object Promise]
2022-09-07T06:11:32.003Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2022-09-07T06:11:32.003Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2022-09-07T06:11:32.003Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2022-09-07T06:11:32.004Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing bootstrap, that's how I solved it.

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```